# can't open xampp control panel in ubuntu 17.10..how to fix this error?

Tags: xampp

**ERROR:**

> No protocol specified
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py:57:
>   GtkWarning: could not open display   warnings.warn(str(e),
>   _gtk.Warning) Error importing pygtk2 and pygtk2-libglade

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @Gezzasa it is ubuntu 17.10

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YKCW8lAkd8

Comment: Haha, i'm so blind some times. Clear as day in your heading. The youtube vid I posted is all I could find

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @Gezzasa yes but i got an another error

Comment: You'l need to ask another question then, haha. update this one. I'm only googling to try help you. I don't have experience with Linux :)